# Can circular light be produced with more than one vector, tracing out multi stranded strand helixes in space?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it possible to construct circular light with more than one vector tracing out a one strand helix in space? For example, circular light with two vectors in opposite directions (on the same line), tracing out a double helix like in DNA, or three, each with an angle of 120 degrees with respect to one another, tracing out a three-stranded helix like those salty things you can eat?

Comment: I'll disappoint you, circular light doesn't even produce single-stranded helices.

Comment: @LLIAMnYP But a rotating e.m. field vector, wich has a forwards velocity, traces out a spiral, doesn´t it? Enlighten me!

Comment: So light travels along a *straight* line. And along this line the direction of the EM field changes. But the electric field is *on this line*! You're trying to say that since we have a field of, say, 1V/cm pointing up, there's an actual point in space, say, 1cm above the line that has physical significance.

Comment: Here's how the electric field of a plane circular wave looks vs. (x,y,z) coordinate. http://i.stack.imgur.com/yODXJ.png Once you stop considering a single line with constant y-z and look at the picture as a whole, and stop associating an electric field (in V/cm) with an actual displacement (in cm), you can realize, that the concept of a spiral is kinda' meaningless.

Comment: And of course, sure, you can say, let's consider a line along x with constant y-z, and look at the electric field at each point, and for every V/cm of E-field we will displace ourselves by 1 cm in the direction of the field and then we will get a helix. But that doesn't carry much meaning. But by this logic, since the field is uniquely defined at every point, we will only ever get a single helix.

Comment: But isn´t there a possibility to superimpose two rotating field vectors, pointing in opposite directions, so the end points of the two vectors trace out a double helix. Or three, four, five, etc. vectors, all having the same angle  with respect to their neighbour vectors?

Comment: Let me stress, that there's no helix in real space first. Yes, you can superimpose two electric fields with opposite directions. The principle of superposition will state, that they *cancel each other out*.

Comment: You can't just say "this is one electric field, producing one helix, and this is another". The electric field at every point in space is the sum of electric fields from every source. They add up to one specific vector.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to construct circular light with more than one vector tracing out a one strand helix in space?

Yes. Check out work by the [Glasgow optics team](http://www.gla.ac.uk/schools/physics/research/groups/optics/research/orbitalangularmomentum/) headed up by Miles Padgett:

[image]
<sup>OAM = -1 hbar per photon (right-hand helical phase front)</sup>

> For example, circular light with two vectors in opposite directions (on the same line), tracing out a double helix like in DNA

As above:

[image]
<sup>OAM = +2 hbar per photon (two-fold helix)</sup>

> or three, each with an angle of 120 degrees with respect to one another, tracing out a three-stranded helix like those salty things you can eat?

As above:

[image]
<sup>OAM = +3 hbar per photon (three-fold helix: fusilli)</sup>